# Is it possible to redirect/forward GSM call to VOIP?

Tags: android, voip

I am working on project with following functionality.

- Incoming GSM call after few seconds should be forwarded to VOIP number over Wifi.
- Anyone from Laptop/Desktop PC should be able to establish GSM call using android phone over Wifi.

To achieve this following components will be required

- VOIP System (Asterisk)
- Android client with functionality of incoming call Interception, VOIP agent and forwarding incoming GSM call to voip number
- Windows Desktop Application to listen forwarded calls by Android and to establish outgoing GSM calls.

Is it feasible to redirect/forward incoming GSM call to voip number over Wifi and establish outgoing call using android over Wifi

Answer (score 0):

The more usual way to do this would be to simply add a GSM card into your Asterisk VoIP system.

This is quite a common use case and there are multiple suppliers of such cards for Asterisk systems available.

There is even at least one standalone IP to WiFi Asterisk based box available (google GOIP) and there may be others also.

I don't believe that Android as it currently is implemented at the time of writing will allow you to connect a call from GSM to a WiFi VoIP call on the device itself.